# Appcelerator Android Push with AWS SNS

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, amazon-sns

I'm developing an app for both iOS and Android.
We're using AWS SNS for Push Notifications.
iOS runs fine, but for Android I receive a push event but the payload is empty no matter what we try in SNS. (Have tried to push via Arrow and it works fine, so it feels like a problem in SNS)

Is there anybody out there who have done the same and got it to work?

Comment: Which module are you using for handling the notification coming via AWS SNS in Appcelerator when you use Android?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to put the payload inside the data object.

```
"data":{
   "payload":{
        "android": {
             "alert": "This is a message from my own server"
        }
    }
}
```

[source of solution](https://developer.appcelerator.com/question/179088/empty-payload-when-sending-push-notifications-from-a-third-party-server)

Comment: Can you please share example for SNS implementation in Titanium application?